# Sharepoint synchrounous event receivers

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, event-receiver

I have a question about the synchrounous event receivers in Sharepoint 2007.

As example, lets look at the event **ItemUpdating**: Is it safe to assume that the update operation **will succeed** if I don't cancel it manually? I know the event could be cancelled by another event receiver. But assume that there is no other event receiver and that SP will act normally (no full DB or any other exceptional issues..)

I am asking because I want to perform some actions that makes only sense if the event was successful. However because the asynchrounous "event properties" lack a lot of information, I have to use the synchrounous events instead.

Thanks for feedback

Comment: By "lack a lot of information" do you mean that properties.ListItem will no longer have the original values? Because otherwise both methods receive only an SPItemEventProperties parameter. Perhaps you could include some code or more detail of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I need to see the actual changes on an item: Comparing old to new values. Unfortunately this is not possible in ItemUpdated.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use `ItemUpdated` instead of `ItemUpdating`. That way, you know the event was successfull and you can perform your actions. Otherwise, I think `ItemUpdating` works pretty well. Is there a reason you are worried?